# When are groups of order 12 non-abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am currently reading http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/group12.pdf, and have a quick question about the group being non-abelian. Let me explain:

Let $|G|=12=2^2\cdot 3$ and let $n_2,$ $n_3$ denote the number of Sylow $2,3$-subgroups respectively. By using Sylow's Theorems and counting elements we see that either $n_3=1$, or $n_3=4$ (and $n_2=1$). So we always have a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup or a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup.

On page 2 the author turns to the case $n_2\ne 1$ (so $n_2=3$, $n_3=1$) and says "*Since $n_2\ne 1$, the group is non-abelian*". Why is this true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the second Sylow theorem, any Sylow 2-subgroups are conjugates of each other.  But in an abelian group, every conjugate is the same subgroup again.

Comment: So in an abelian group any $n_p$ (denoting the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups) must be $1$?

Comment: @Thomas Yes.  Any finite abelian group is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 So e.g. $C_3\times C_4\times C_4$ is the product of its Sylow 3-subgroup $C_3\times \{e\}\times \{e\}$ and its Sylow $2$-subgroup $\{e\}\times C_4\times C_4$ ?